# Python Code when submitted returns Runtime Error - NZEC

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, factorial, pyhook

```
def fact(y):
    if y == 1 or y == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return y*fact(y-1)

x,n= map(int,input().split())

f = fact(n)%10
l = x**f

print(l%10)
```

It was getting submitted partially.

Comment: What is the exact error you get and what are the inputs that you provide to the code that produce the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**most likely** value of y is greater than 10^4. python's recursion stack space is 10^4. if this space runs out compiler throws nzec
this can be prevented by adding this.set the limit according to the max length of y.

```
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10**9)
```

Add constraints from next time.